# html button does not change color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet

i am working with liflet API.
i create markers on a map.
when a marker is pressed a popup uppers.
in the pop up there are two buttons.
what i am trying to do is to make the buttons change color when they are pressed.
the problem is that when i try to reset the color when the popup is opened to the original one
the affect happens only when i open the popup a second time.
i checked the popup event and the click event work.
button creation code:

```
if(!marker.getPopup()){
        var tooltipContent = $('<div />');
        $.each(marker._myId, function(index,value){
            var current = $("<button id=\"router-"+value.properties.name+"\" type=\"button\" style=\"width:100%;color:black\" class='tooltipName' >"+value.properties.name+"</button>")
                .click(function(){
                    handleClickOnSwitch(value);
                    var button=$("#router-"+value.properties.name);
                    button.css("background-color","grey");

                });
            tooltipContent=tooltipContent.append(current);
        });
        marker.bindPopup(tooltipContent[0],{'closeButton' : false,}).openPopup();
    }
```

on click i change the button coller to grey.
each time the popup is opened i call:

```
function resetButtonPress(marker){
    $.each(marker._myId, function(index,router){
        var button=$("#router-"+router.properties.name);
        button.css("background-color","RGB(221,221,221)");
    });
}
```

i would appreciate any help.

Comment: jsfiddle or it didn't happened.

Comment: i can't post the whole code here because of its dependency on out side events.

Comment: I'm talking about jsfiddle.net make a fiddle, if you are using libraries you can always add external links at the left menu, and finally save&share your work here so we can see it working easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end the root cause of the issue was a race condition.
the button element i was trying to update was not created fast enough and as a result 
the color change did not take affect.
my solution to this was to create the buttons in the popup every time it opens.
this way i can circumvent the problem.